# Rails 3 Select box posts a blank variable but the HTML is well-formed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, validation

I'm having problems with the `select` tag in my view.

First of all I'm using `Rails 3.1.1` and `Ruby 1.9.2 p290`

The model is a Consumable which has a name, supplier, reorder number, type and associated printer models that it is compatible with.

The field that isn't validating correctly is `type` which is fed values from an array in the Consumable model and the validation should be against inclusion of one of the elements of the array.

In the model, I define the field's validation like so

```
  TYPES = [ "REM", "REM-HICAP", "OEM", "OEM-HICAP" ]
  validates :type, inclusion: TYPES
```

In the view (form partial for Consumable) I've created the select tag thusly

```
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label "Type" %><br />
  <%= f.select :type, Consumable::TYPES, prompt: 'Select a type...',
               :selected => params[:type] %>
</div>
```

The drop-down box is creating well-formed HTML which looks like this

```
<div class="field">
  <label for="consumable_Type">Type</label><br />
  <select id="consumable_type" name="consumable[type]">
    <option value="">Select a type...</option>
    <option value="REM">REM</option>
    <option value="REM-HICAP">REM-HICAP</option>
    <option value="OEM">OEM</option>
    <option value="OEM-HICAP">OEM-HICAP</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

When I post the form this is the debug information

```
---
utf8: ?
_method: put
authenticity_token: nZZ9MastYswVCDrvAbgVLTUWqSRZLVrvRLmxOqPYk7I=
consumable:
  description: Black Toner
  supplier_id: '1'
  reorder_no: '123456'
  type: OEM
  printer_model_ids:
  - '1'
  - '3'
commit: Update Consumable
action: update
controller: consumables
id: '1'
```

As is evident by the debug info, type is set correctly with a value from the select box (a string) and `type` in the model is a `string`. The form instead shows the validation error "Type is not included in the list" and if I remove the validation the database shows a nil value for the `type` field.

At what point is the validation applied to the form, does the controller trigger it by attempting to save the object?

I have used the same method of validating a drop-down box in the `depot` application in Agile Web Development with Rails 4th Edition with essentially the same code but a different name for the array and it works correctly.

I have just tested the same validation in the `depot` application and it works on this same workstation, so I would count out setup inconsistencies.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered my error: `Type` is protected in Rails and changing my variable name to `Kind` make it work correctly.